# If the asymptotic density of some subset becomes null, does the sum of reciprocals of some subset become convergent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with the property that there exists a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that the upper asymptotic density of $A$ is strictly positive, but the asymptotic density of $f(A)$ is null, is there a subset $B \subseteq A$ such that the sum of the reciprocals of the elements in $B$ diverges, but the sum of the reciprocals of the elements in $f(B)$ converges ?

Some context : there is a relation between topologies which really interests me recently, which is when for two topologies $T_1, T_2$ on a set $X$, if a function from $X$ to $X$ is continuous for $T_1$, it is continuous for $T_2$. I try to find some examples, and it’s perhaps the case for two topologies on $\mathbb{N}$ which are all the subsets with asymptotic density of 1, and all the subsets such that the sum of the reciprocals of their complement converges.

My intuition tells me that it’s not true, but I can’t find a counterexample. The most "gentle" way that I see to retire some density is to multiply n by $\log(n)$ and to round up, but $\sum_{i=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n*\log(n)}$ diverges, and $\sum_{i=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n * \log(n) * \log(n * \log(n))} < \sum_{i=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n * \log(n)^2}$ converges. If I multiply by $\log(\log(\log(\dots \log(n+c))\dots)$ for a sufficiently great $c$, I have a similar counterexample.